# C# Serial Port BNO055 Sensor Communication

Tags: c#, mono, serial-port, raspberry-pi, sensors

I am trying to use C# and mono to talk to an IMU sensor (BNO055) on a raspberry pi. No matter what I do, I cannot read and write successfully to the sensor. Can someone with more experience let me know what the proper way to do this is? Thanks.

Initialization:

```
    private void ConnectToBNO055()
    {
        GPIO.Write(ResetPin, true);
        Task.Delay(650).Wait();

        Port                = new SerialPort();
        Port.PortName       = PortName;
        Port.BaudRate       = 115200;
        Port.Parity         = Parity.None;
        Port.DataBits       = 8;
        Port.StopBits       = StopBits.One;
        Port.Handshake      = Handshake.None;
        Port.ReadTimeout    = 5000;
        Port.WriteTimeout   = 5000;

        try
        {
            Port.Open();

            while (!Port.IsOpen) { Task.Delay(1).Wait(); }

            SetMode(OperationMode.OPERATION_MODE_CONFIG);

            WriteRegister((byte)PageIDRegisterDefinition.BNO055_PAGE_ID_ADDR, 0, false);

            byte chipID = ReadRegister((byte)PageRegisterDefinitionStart.BNO055_CHIP_ID_ADDR);

            if ((byte)I2CAddress.BNO055_ID == chipID)
            {
                Reset();

                WriteRegister((byte)ModeRegisters.BNO055_PWR_MODE_ADDR, (byte)PowerMode.POWER_MODE_NORMAL); 

                WriteRegister((byte)ModeRegisters.BNO055_SYS_TRIGGER_ADDR, 0x0); 

                SetMode(OperationMode.OPERATION_MODE_NDOF);

                Connected = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to IMU.");

                Console.WriteLine("Calibrating IMU. . .");

                BNO055.CalibrationStatus lastCal;
                BNO055.CalibrationStatus cal = GetCalibrationStatus();

                Console.WriteLine("System: " + cal.System.ToString() + ", Magnometer: " + cal.Mag.ToString() + ", Gyroscope: " + cal.Gyro.ToString() + ", Accelerometer: " + cal.Accel.ToString());
                while (cal.System != 3 || cal.Mag != 3 || cal.Gyro != 3 || cal.Accel != 3)
                {
                    Task.Delay(250).Wait();

                    lastCal = cal;
                    cal = GetCalibrationStatus();

                    if (cal.Accel != lastCal.Accel || cal.Gyro != lastCal.Gyro || cal.Mag != lastCal.Mag || cal.System != lastCal.System)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("System: " + cal.System.ToString() + ", Magnometer: " + cal.Mag.ToString() + ", Gyroscope: " + cal.Gyro.ToString() + ", Accelerometer: " + cal.Accel.ToString());
                    }
                }

                Calibrated = true;
                Console.WriteLine("IMU Calibrated.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to IMU.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to IMU.");
        }
    }
```

IO Methods:

```
    private void WriteRegister(byte address, byte data, bool ack = true)
    {
        byte[] writeBuffer = new byte[] { 0xAA, 0x00, address, 1, data };
        byte[] response;
        try
        {
            response = WriteData(writeBuffer, ack);
            if (ack)
            {
                if (0xEE01 != (response[0] << 8 | response[1]))
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("WriteRegister returned 0x{0:x2},0x{1:x2}", response[0], response[1]));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("WriteRegister error: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }

    private byte ReadRegister(byte register)
    {
        byte[] commandBuffer = new byte[] { 0xAA, 0x01, register, 1 };
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1];
        try
        {
            readBuffer = ReadData(commandBuffer, 1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ReadRegister error: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
        return readBuffer[0];
    }

    private byte[] WriteData(byte[] command, bool ack = true, int retries = 5)
    {
        byte[] ackBuffer = new byte[2];
        bool done = false;

        while ((!done) && (retries-- > 0))
        {
            Port.Write(command, 0, command.Length);

            if (ack)
            {
                while (Port.BytesToRead != 2) { Task.Delay(1).Wait(); }
                Port.Read(ackBuffer, 0, 2);

                done = 0xEE07 != (ackBuffer[0] << 8 | ackBuffer[1]);
            }
            else
                done = true;
        }

        if (!done)
            throw new Exception("WriteData retries exceeded");
        return ackBuffer;
    }

    private byte[] ReadData(byte[] command, int readLength)
    {
        byte[] headerBuffer = new byte[2];
        byte[] returnBuffer = new byte[readLength];

        Port.Write(command, 0, command.Length);

        while (Port.BytesToRead != 2) { Task.Delay(1).Wait(); }
        Port.Read(headerBuffer, 0, 2);

        if (headerBuffer[0] != 0xBB)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("ReadData error 0x{0:x2}{1:x2}", headerBuffer[0], headerBuffer[1]));
        if (headerBuffer[1] != readLength)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("ReadData error: failed to read {0} bytes.  Read {1}", readLength, headerBuffer[1]));

        while (Port.BytesToRead != readLength) { Task.Delay(1).Wait(); }
        Port.Read(returnBuffer, 0, readLength);

        return returnBuffer;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your serial port initialisation code as well please.

Comment: and: what happens? any of the exceptions thrown, empty buffer returned?

Comment: Sure just posted it above. And it is throwing the first exception in ReadData method

Comment: The exception prints: ReadRegister error: ReadData error 0xeeee

Comment: Your code does not show the calls to WriteData & ReadData. If you have just done a WriteData then looking at the data sheet - it appears that the device may respond with an acknowledge first byte of which is 0xEE. In your exception code you are displaying that byte twice - you need to change the string to _"ReadData error 0x{0:x2}{1:x2}"_ to see what the second byte is - if it is 0x01 that is indicating success. 0xEE is also used as a read response, the second byte shows the actual error.

Comment: Okay, I listed the two calling methods above and changed the string! The new error message says "ReadRegister error: ReadData error 0xee01"

Comment: As far as I can see you will always get an acknowledge response following a write to the registers. In your code you are ignoring the acknowledge response on the initial WriteRegister, but this is still sent so will be in the port input buffer - hence on your read the first data you get is 0xEE01 which is the "Write Success" response from the write commend.

Comment: Makes sense, so is there a way to clear the port input buffer after it is read or to only read the last set of bytes? Sorry I am a novice to all this.

Comment: As the write commands return an acknowledge response - it would seem a good idea to always read these to ensure the command was successful. I am not completely familiar with the Serial Port class for the Pi - but you should find there is something like a _DiscardInputBuffer()_ method that you can call prior to any command just to make sure that no data is sitting there - but don't forget each byte takes about 0.8ms to arrive at 115200baud, so you would need to ensure at least 1.6ms delay after a write command to ignore the response - so you may as well just read it.

Comment: Note - reading the buffer takes the characters out of the buffer too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I was trying to read a response from the sensor immediately after writing data. To solve the problem, add a loop waiting for the BytesToRead property to be equal to the desired response length then read.